# htaccess redirect from subsubdomain to subsubsubdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm setting up a new subdomain on our development server to deploy a copy of our new website.
The copy of the site is set out like this: `site.develop.rav.domain.co.uk`

Annoyingly all links and resources are generating their links to `develop.rav.domain.co.uk`

Trying to use htaccess to solve this, as has been previously managed with another subsubsubdomain.  Here's what I have but it isnt working

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^develop\.rav\.domain\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.develop.rav.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Not done much with htaccess before so any help will be appreciated

On closer inspection the URL being written for resources is: `ukcl-rav-vdev01\.rav\.contactlaw\.co.uk`

Comment: Rule looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: All links go to 2 subs rather than 3 subs.  So no css/js/images are being accessed.  A lot of links are off too.  It might help to mention this is a wordpress site

Comment: Is `http://site.develop.rav.domain.co.uk/` WP site OR `http://develop.rav.domain.co.uk/` is WP site OR both?

Comment: `http://site.develop.rav.domain.co.uk/` is WP `http://develop.rav.domain.co.uk/` doesnt actually have anything pointing to it. The htaccess is definitely being accessed as garbage will cause an internal error

Comment: on closer inspection WP is actually writing addresses as `http://develop.rav.domain.co.uk/site`

Comment: Yes you will need to change permalink settings in WP

Comment: But unfortunately I cant access the admin section because the addresses are being written incorrectly

Comment: Have done so since.  First time I've had to properly use WordPress, more used to joomla and obviously couldnt find the setting in the config .php files (which is where this equivalent setting is in Joomla)  Thanks for your help!